# Authenticate anonymously with roles

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony-3.4, symfony-guard

I have an Authenticator that needs to authenticate the user anonymously, but include a role. I do this by overriding `createAuthenticatedToken` in the Authenticator:

```php
class ClientAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    // supports(), getCredentials(), all working

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        return new SessionUser;
    }

    // Return an anonymous user with the client role
    public function createAuthenticatedToken(UserInterface $user, $providerKey)
    {
        return new AnonymousToken(
            'Ynpir6i',                // <-- here's the issue (the $secret param)
            'anon.',
            ['ROLE_CLIENT_GUEST']
        );
    }
}
```

This works wonderfully -- when I hard-code the "secret" parameter of AnonymousToken.

I cannot figure out how to get this secret dynamically though. It is not the "secret" parameter provided in parameters.yml (aka `%kernel.secret%`).

I only got the secret I'm using now by dumping it out when it's set in `AnonymousAuthenticationListener`. I've looked at that service's configuration and I don't see it set at all.

What is this secret parameter, and how can I inject it into my Authenticator?

Or, is there a better way to add roles to an anonymous token that was authenticated a specific way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That parameter may be set to a known value in `security.yml`:

```yaml
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            anonymous:
                secret: '%secret%'
```